# Facebook Login Button changing text programatically in 2 languages

Tags: android, facebook, authentication

Android Application.
I have a view where I added the LoginButton from Facebook and I want to add custom text in the language I need and a form with username and password.
My app is in two languages. When I open the activity containing my button, it shows "Login with Facebook".
I change language, then the button gets my custom text in the specified language. When I want to write something in the form, the text from the Login Button changes back to "Login with Facebook".
Is there any posibility to make the change of the text consistent, so it will never change back to "Login with Facebook"?
Maybe extending the LoginButton class,  but I can't see how. 
I hope you understand my question. This doesn't need code.
Thank you for your help!

Update:
I found a solution: extending the facebook login button class and Override the onLayout method like the code below.

```
public class CustomLoginButton extends LoginButton
{
    Context mContext;

    public CustomLoginButton(Context context)
    {
        super(context);
        mContext = context;
    }

    public CustomLoginButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs)
    {
        super(context, attrs);
        mContext = context;
    }

    public CustomLoginButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle)
    {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        mContext = context;
    }


    @Override
    protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int left, int top, int right, int bottom)
    {
        super.onLayout(changed, left, top, right, bottom);
        final String fbButtonLabel;
        if (this.getId() == R.id.login_button)
        {
            fbButtonLabel = getActivity().getResources().getString(R.string.custom_login_text);
            this.setText(fbButtonLabel);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should create different strings.xml for different languages.

Read:
[Localizing with Resources](http://developer.android.com/intl/ja/guide/topics/resources/localization.html)